# componentDidMount multiple fetch calls best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a lot of APIs that are INDEPENDENT of each other and needs to be stored in the React state before it is rendered. I have `fetch` calls in `componentDidMount` but I am not sure what is the best way to approach this.
Should I...

1. have nested fetch calls

example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('url')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // call another fetch in here
    })

}
```

OR
2. have separate fetch calls

example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('url')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // set state in here
    })
    
    // call another fetch for the other url endpoint
    fetch('url2')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // set state in here
    })
}
```

I'm not sure if one way is considered better practice over the other, but I would love to know what you guys think and what some of the pros/cons would be.

UPDATE: I am using `Promise.all()` now, but I am getting the Promise returned rather than the actual value. Here is my code:

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(`/api/url1`),
  fetch(`/api/url2`),
])
.then(([res1, res2]) => (
  {
    res1: res1.json(),
    res2: res2.json(),
}))
.then(({res1, res2}) => {
  this.setState({
    state1: res1,
    state2: res2,
  });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

When I checked the values of my state on the console, here is what I get:

```
Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(6530)
```

Any idea of what I may be missing / doing wrong?

Comment: If they're not dependent on each other, definitely don't nest them. Use `Promise.all` to render *once* instead of twice

Comment: I'm using Promise.all(), but in my .then() function, I'm getting the actual promise returned compared to the promise value (an array of objects in my case). Any idea of what I may be doing wrong? I also updated my post with my new code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @CertainPerformance mentioned, you should use `Promise.all` method.

```
Promise.all([
  fetch("url1"),
  fetch("url2"),
  fetch("url3"),
]).then(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
  this.setState({status: "fetched"})
})
```

```js
const url = "https://asdqwe.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path";

const promises = Promise.all([
  fetch(url),
  fetch(url),
  fetch(url),
]);


promises
  .then((results) => 
    Promise.all(results.map(r => r.text()))
  )
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: I am using something similar to your approach, but I am getting the actual Promise returned rather than the value. I have updated my original post with my new code!

Comment: I've added the snippet to my original answer, I think it should help to understand.

Answer (score 12):

As far as `fetch` returns `Promise` you can use `Promise.all` function to execute both fetches in parallel:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([fetch('url'), fetch('url2')])

      .then(([res1, res2]) => { 
         return Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()]) 
      })
      .then(([res1, res2]) => {
        // set state in here
      });
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  and just wondering, would this work for axios too if i don't use the fetch() method?

Comment: Hey! So i think it seems to be working, but in the second .then() method, i am getting the promise returned rather than the actual data. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @kennycodes I forgot that `response.json()` also returns a `Promise`. I have editted my answer. Now it should work